# Create MySql docker image with preloaded data

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a Dockerfile that uses the MySql 5.7 Docker image and copies a SQL script that I have to create the database schema on first startup.  I create a container with that image and use `docker commit` to create a new image from that container.  If I create a new container using that new image, then the schema is created again rather then restored from the previous `commit`.

My understanding is this is because, as per the [docker commit documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/):

> The commit operation will not include any data contained in volumes mounted inside the container.

And the SQL data is stored in [a volume defined in the MySql Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/e0d43b2a29867c5b7d5c01a8fea30a086861df2b/5.7/Dockerfile.oracle#L125), so that explains it.

However, [the MySql docker documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) also states:

> You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed data

I'm not sure how to "provide custom images with contributed data".  Any ideas?

Thank you